# Cannot get data outside socket.on

Tags: socket.io

There is one problem when I try to get value from socket.on. Can not get value even push it into array. I have to use axios but are there any way for it ?

My code:

```
    `var array = new Array();

    socket.on("abc", function(data)
    {
         array.push(data); 
         console.log(JSON.stringify(array)); // work ok
    }

console.log(JSON.stringify(array)); // problem here -> empty value
`
```

Any help was appreciated.

Comment: `socket.on` is an [asynchronous event](https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem. You are creating an array and set a callback function for 'abc' event on socket and log your array to console. Note that callback function will be execute later, when socket receive abc event. Your array contains data after first time callback execution.
your code will be execute in this way:

```
    1: `var array = new Array();`
    2: set a callback function for abc event on your socket
    3: `console.log(JSON.stringify(array)); // array is empty`
    4: when abc event received on socket, function(data) will be run
    5: now array is not empty
```

I hope this can help you

Comment: Thanks, Milad. I will try and give the result I have.